# Cannot access Group admin - missing API key

Tags: drupal, api, groups

CMS: Drupal 7.56 (shared hosting at Siteground; cpanel/phpmyadmin access)
Civicrm version: 4.6.34 (followng problem follows recent update)

I (admin 1 - all civicrm persmissions) cannot access Contacts > Manage Groups. Receive the following screen message:
[image: API Key Required]

On selecting 'Return to home page' link, the following errors show:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'group_name' in CRM_Core_BAO_Setting::getItems() (line 332 of [path edited].../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Setting.php).
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in CRM_Core_BAO_Setting::getItems() (line 332 of [path edited]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Setting.php).
Warning: Illegal string offset 'group_name' in CRM_Core_BAO_Setting::getItems() (line 332 of [path edited]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Setting.php).
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in CRM_Core_BAO_Setting::getItems() (line 332 of [path edited]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Setting.php).
```

Group contacts can be searched (through Contact > Find Contacts > enter group name in search box). Result provides url like:
`base_url/civicrm/contact/search?_qf_Basic_display=true&qfKey=9f41ad4096614eb353cac129b335e58a_757` which indicates a valid key existing.

[Edit]: having logged out of CiviCRM and returned, receive following message (civi alert message in top right): "Count data for smart groups is not currently calculated. You may click Update Smart Groups to generate it. Be aware this can cause significant server load".

[Edit 2]: Drupal error logs show:

$backTrace = #0 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(446): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) #1 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(57): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(InvalidArgumentException)) #2 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(482): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2)) #3 internal function: civicrm_invoke("group") #4 /includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:1)) #5 /index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() #6 {main}

And:

```
$Fatal Error Details = Array ( [message] => id (value: 1006'A=0) is not of the type Positive [code] => )
```

Any pointers most gratefully received.

SJ

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get the Mailchimp extension to work properly?

Comment: Hi, This is not an answer to the question and does not seem related.  Please post this a new question and provide details of what is not working properly.

Answer (score 3):

After putting site into maintenance mode, enabling Debugging and Error handling, it became clear that this was related to the Mailchimp extension. I have disabled the extension and will reconfigure. Manage Groups now fine.
Apologies for wasting anyone's time.

Comment: This is happening for me too and i have mailchimp extension installed too. Did you figured out the solution?